# Need an algorithm to calculate the size of a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, graphics, graph, geometry, 2d

I get a logical riddle and I need an efficient algorithm to solve it.

I have large rectangle (box) with size w*h (width*height).

I have also x other rectangles with not size but with fixed proportions.

What is the fastest way to get the x that will let each of the X rectangle the maximum size to be inside the box(large rectangle)?

Example:

The box rectangle size is 150* 50 (width * height) and i have 25 small rectangles.

The fixed proportion of the small rectangle is 3 (if height =5 then width =5*3=15).
Lets call the height of the rectangle x.

I want to find that largest X that will let me to insert all the rectangle into the big rectangle (into the box).

(The small rectangles will be placed in rows and columns, for example 5 columns and 5 rows by the proportion and maximum height)

Does anyone know an efficient algorithm to solve this?

Comment: I tried to take the maximum size of small rectangles and also the minimum and calculate how many rows and columns needed and then measure the maximum size as vector. It's not such a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Um what?

Isn't it just (w*h)/75?

Yeah, brackets aren't needed... but isn't that what you want? Or am i totes missing something here?

Where w and h are the dimensions of the big or parent rectangle.
And 75 is 3*25.

Comment: In the example I don't know the size of the small rectangle. This is what i want to find. I only know the proportion between height and width. In the real situation I know the big rectangle size, number of small rectangles and proportion between height and width.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to solve this problem empirically (solve using [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)) instead of analytically, i.e. find all possibilities* (I'll explain the *). Essentially we want to place every rectangle starting with as small as that rect can be to its maximum size (max size can be defined by largest the rectangle can be before bumping into the start point of its neighbors or growing to the container master rect). What this means is if we attempt to place every rect in its every possible size, one of those solutions will be the best solution. Also note that this really a one dimentional problem since the rects height and width is bound by a ratio; setting one implicitly sets the other.

* - When I said all possibilities, I really meant most reasonable possibilities. Since we are in floating point space we cannot test ALL possibilities. We can test for finer and finer precision, but will be unable to test all sizes. Due to this we define a step size to iterate through the size of the rects we will try.

```
const float STEP_SIZE = 0.0001;
float fLastTotalSize = 0;

int main()
{
  PlaceRect(myRects.begin(), myRects.end());
}

void PlaceRect(Iterator currentRect, Iterator end)
{
  if (currentRect == end)
  {
    return;
  }

  float fRectMaxSize = CalculateMaxPossibleRectSize(*currentRect);

  // find the number of steps it will take to iterate from the smallest 
  // rect size to the largest
  int nSteps = fRectMaxSize / STEP_SIZE;

  for(int i = 0; i < nSteps; ++i)
  {
    // based on the step index scale the rect size
    float fCurrentRectTestSize = i*STEP_SIZE;

    currentRect->SetSize(fCurrentRectTestSize);

    float fTotalSize = CalculateTotalSizesOfAllRects();
    if (fTotalSize > fLastTotalSize)
    {
      fLastTotalSize = fTotalSize;
      SaveRectConfiguration();
    }

    // Continue placing the rest of the rects assuming the size 
    // we just set for the current rect 
    PlaceRect(currentRect + 1, end);

    // Once we return we can now reset the current rect size to 
    // something else and continue testing possibilities 
  }
}
```

Based on the step size and the number of rectangles this may run for a very long time, but will find you the empirical solution.